# What are the main adjustments to do when setting up crashlytics on my development android application?

Tags: android, sdk, application-settings

I'm building an application for android and im trying to add a button for crashlytics I've successfully ran the application but however the crashlytics button is not working out with me this is my code for the app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eleenai"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

this is my mainActivity

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val crashButton = Button(this)
        crashButton.text = "Crash!"
        crashButton.setOnClickListener {
            Crashlytics.getInstance().crash() // Force a crash
        }

        addContentView(crashButton, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it doesn't work? Afaik, `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()` will actually crash your app. The crash report will be send upon next restart.

However:

a) Crashlytics is deprecated and has been replaced with Firebase. It won't work after March 31st 2020.

b) I don't see any code where you initialize Crashlytics as described in the [installation guide](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install). You also have to add your API key to the `manifest.xml`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```